# Экспорт большой таблицы из БД на C#

Tags: c#, sql, export

Возникла необходимость периодической выгрузки большой таблицы (более 7млн строк) из базы данных в CSV. Если делать это инструментами экспорта из какой-нибудь среды типа Aqua DataStudio или PostgreSQL, то экспорт занимает 2-3 минуты. 
Я написал программу, которая экспортирует результат в csv, но она потребляет больше 2ГБ ОЗУ и работает больше 15 минут. 
Что можно попробовать для оптимизации?
Код прилагаю. Спасибо!

```
 public void RecordFile(DataTable dt)
    {//Запись данных в csv
        //Шапка
        StreamWriter swc = new StreamWriter("C:\test.csv", false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
        var columns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>();
        swc.WriteLine(string.Join(";", columns));
        swc.Close();
        //Строки
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\test.csv", true, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
            sw.WriteLine(string.Join(";", dt.Rows[i].ItemArray));
            sw.Close();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        dt.Clear();
    }
```

Я так понимаю, что основная проблема в размещении данных. Я помещаю весь массив в DataTable и записываю его в файл, а готовые среды пишут в режиме онлайн(не из дампа памяти).

Comment: сколько итоговый файл занимает? сервер удаленный, сохраняете по сети, или локально?

Comment: Не надо создавать StreamWriter на каждую операцию, создайте один раз. И `Close` вызывается либо в `finally` блоке или вместо него используется `using`.

Comment: И вместо DataTable используйте DbDataReader

Comment: *Что можно попробовать для оптимизации?* Просто передавайте SQL-серверу запрос на выгрузку таблицы в файл, а он уже сам всё сделает. А тащить всё к себе, потом валить в файл... вот оно надо?

Comment: Да наверняка открытие-закрытие потока сильно тормозит. Из-за того, что это делается каждую строчку, буферизация вообще не используется.

Comment: @teran около 200мб, удаленный сервер

Comment: @Vasek спасибо! Это действительно помогло, глупая ошибка...